# Comment orthographier les préfectures du Japon ?

Tags: orthographe, noms-propres, japonais

I was just wondering how native French speakers commonly spell 京都: "**Kyoto**" or "**Kyôto**"? And how about 東京 and 大阪: "**Tokyo/Osaka**" or "**Tôkyo/Ôsaka**"?

Do they follow certain rules of spelling? I can only find some contradicting info on the Web. I'm not sure which one to use for my Profile page.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Tôkyô? More specialised stuff, written by or for a public that has some knowledge of Japanese, has the circumflex marking long vowels, but it's common to omit them. Tokyo especially is pronounced /tɔkjɔ/ rather than /tokjo/ which is more consistent with the circumflex-less spelling.

Comment: @Eauquidort: oh, is word-final /ɔ/ still in common use? I had the impression that it was merged into /o/ for most people, but as a learner, my perspective of French phonology is heavily biased towards fairly contemporary Parisian accents.

Comment: @sumelic: Oh right, I forgot. They're merged in most varieties, afaik only Belgium, Franche-Comté and bits of Switzerland still make the distinction. There's old folks here in Belgium who still have a diphtong for "(e)au" - [ɔo̯]

Comment: The accents on Tōkyō must be here when writing it in rōmaji. But I would say in pure French, you can omit them, especially since macrons don't exist in French.

Comment: Un exemple variable, [_place de Kyōto_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_de_Ky%C5%8Dto) avec le macron, et _place de Tokyo_ sans macron, les deux à Paris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a l'[*Arrêté français du 4 novembre 1993 relatif à la terminologie des noms d'États et de capitales*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9_fran%C3%A7ais_du_4_novembre_1993_relatif_%C3%A0_la_terminologie_des_noms_d%27%C3%89tats_et_de_capitales#Diacritiques) qui peut avoir un impact au niveau normatif car il dispose que « les noms de pays et de villes étant des noms propres, il est recommandé de respecter la graphie locale en usage, translittérée ou non. On ne portera cependant pas les signes diacritiques particuliers s'ils n'existent pas dans l'écriture du français. ». Suivant cette règle, le [macron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo#D.C3.A9nomination_de_Tokyo_et_de_ses_habitants) serait exclu de l'orthographe de ces noms. Par ailleurs est annexé à l'arrêté une [liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9_fran%C3%A7ais_du_4_novembre_1993_relatif_%C3%A0_la_terminologie_des_noms_d%27%C3%89tats_et_de_capitales#Liste_annex.C3.A9e_FGHIJ) de noms de pays avec leur capitale et *Tokyo* y apparaît sans aucun accent, quoique la règle n'empêcherait pas une [autre graphie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22126/comment-orthographier-les-pr%C3%A9fectures-du-japon#comment42872_22126) qui pourrait être compatible. On a retrouvé l'orthographe sans accent dans des exemples au Canada sur [*Termium*](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/noms-geographiques-etrangers) (on réfère a un emploi identique anglais/français pour ce nom) et à la [*BDL*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21201/la-typographie/majuscules/emploi-de-la-majuscule-pour-des-types-de-denominations/majuscule-aux-noms-dententes-juridiques-et-politiques), dans ce dernier cas cependant dans le contexte du nom d'un instrument normatif : le *protocole de Kyoto*. On a trouvé sur un [site cadre](http://unfccc.int/portal_francophone/essential_background/kyoto_protocol/items/3274.php) des Nations Unies pour le protocole, la graphie sans accent en français. Personnellement j'ai toujours écrit *Tokyo* ou *Kyoto* sans accent mais je ne suis pas un public particulièrement averti alors je laisse le soin à d'autres de traiter de particularités telles les règles de typographie en usage en domaine spécialisé et l'idée d'authenticité rattachée à la prononciation soit comment *respecter la graphie locale en usage* etc.

Comment: J'ai aussi vérifié au _Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale_, sans trouver rien de particulièrement intéressant; on a un article sur _préfecture_ pour dire qu'il ne prend pas la capitale initiale et on donne _la préfecture de l'Ain_. On a une vedette pour les lettres accentuées dans les langues avec caractères latins où l'on dit que l'accentuation fait partie de l'orthographe, mais c'est ds. un contexte de reproduction de ces langues et non en français. Le LBU14 contient peu ou pas d'exemples avec le Japon ds. les articles consultés. On pensait lire d'autres R.

Answer (score 0):

Des cartes du Japon mentionnent Tôkyô, kyôto, Kôbe... Pour ma part, je suis cette graphie.

Comment: Dans mon atlas, les noms japonais ne portent pas d'accent.

Comment: Il y a une source ?  Voici le [tour] du site et le centre [help].  Quelles cartes à suivre ?